# Symfony 2.5 and own models

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dbal

In Symfony I'm using default ORM Doctrine, but this tool can't give me enough methods to manipulate with different cases. I want to write my own classes and using something like DBAL, just for connections making custom SQL queries and fetch the result. Who can give me some examples? Which classes I should use to make my model layer, extend my functionality.

Comment: You can use native queries with Doctrine, too. Or, if you want a different ORM, have a look at Propel, it also works well with Symfony2.

Comment: Which classes should I extend or implement for writing my own model classes?

Comment: Why did you not read the official documentation of Symfony2 and Doctrine2?

Comment: I read it but sometimes it isn't clear explains some aspects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own SQL query with doctrine you can check that doc page: 
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

but most of the time DQL is more than enough

this is from a project I did, ignore my sql query

```
//Daily Alerts
$dailyAlertsQuery = $em
        ->createQuery("
            SELECT COUNT (a) AS daily
            FROM XXX\xxxBundle\Entity\Alert a
            JOIN a.user u
            WHERE a.mentionUpdate = '1'
            AND u.isActive = '1'
            ")
        ->getResult();

$dailyAlerts = new ArrayCollection($dailyAlertsQuery);
```

Comment: So I can write my own model classes and use it in my controllers, without use SQL code directly in controllers. Because Symfony by default doesn't exists model like definition.

Answer (score 0):

As a good practise, you may put all your custom queries (SQL or DQL) in an [EntityRepository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html)

Here is an example of a custom EntityRepository

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

/**
 * RequestRepository
 *
 */
class RequestRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findByStatus($status = array(), $limit = 5, $orderBy = null)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
        ->select('n')
        ->from('BaseBundle:Request', 'n')
        ->where('n.status IN (:status)')
        ->setParameter('status', $status)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
        if (!is_null($orderBy)) {
            $queryBuilder->orderBy('n.' . $orderBy[0], $orderBy[1]);
        }

        $lines = array();
        foreach ($queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult() as $line) {
            $lines[] = $line;
        }
        return $lines;
    }

    public function getByExpressions($expressions = array(), $limit = 5, $orderBy = null)
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create();
        if (!empty($expressions)) {
            foreach ($expressions as $expression) {
                $criteria->andWhere($expression);
            }
        }
        $criteria->setMaxResults($limit);
        if (!is_null($orderBy)) {
            $criteria->orderBy($orderBy);
        }
        return $this->matching($criteria);
    }
}
```

And in the Entity code, you define this custom repository as follows:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Request
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="request")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BaseBundle\Repository\RequestRepository")
 */
class Request
{
//Entity code, irrelevant here
}
```